# One specific user can't access the shared network drive, how to resolve?

Tags: imac, sharing, smb

I have a network based on a default 192.168.1.1 gateway.

Multiple devices are connected to the network; (3 apple devices, multiple android devices, windows and linux based machines, ).

One of the machines is used as a media server, running windows 10 home, and has 3 shared folders.

Only iMac (Yosemite 10.10.5) is unable to reach the shared folders - giving an error message "there was a problem connecting to server".

iMac does not see the shared folders by Go to Network, also unable use command-k with CIFS:// or SMB:// (getting the error above)

My MBP (El capitan) has no problem seeing the shares, Windows machine is able to see the shared folders on iMac.

- After much network testing, i've created a new user ID on the iMac;
  that test user  sees the shared drive without an issue.
- Safe mode
  does not help
- I
  have deleted the keychain associated with the shared drive, but still
  am getting the error.

Unfortunately I can't switch to a different user currently due to some of the applications installed on this one.

Any recommendations on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Try sudo sysctl -w net.smb.fs.loglevel=255 and see what messages you get in the console window.

See https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/4375/Troubleshooting-File-Sharing-Issues-with-With-Mac-OS-X-and-Windows.html for more info.